# How does PHP merge or push onto an array when I use $array[] = $new_value?

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry, I'm very new to PHP, and I can't find anything about this in The Manual. I understand that to add a new item to the end of an array I can use `array_merge($array, $new_value_array)`, or `array_push($array, $new_value)`, but the manual says this "has the same effect as:"

```
$array[] = $var;
```

repeated for each `var`".

I find the `[] =` technique much neater and more readable, but I'm very curious as to how it works. Is `[]=` an undocumented combination assignment operator or what?

Comment: []= is not an operator itself but a combination of "the end of an array" and the assignment operator.

Comment: Most scripting languages support that array appending syntax. In PHP it uses mostly the same code as `array_push`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fully documented. - **Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: So it is, thanks. I never thought to look in the general 'Arrays' topic, always searching operators and functions.

Comment: Thanks. I spent the last half hour trying to find why such a common operator is undocumented.

Comment: PHP's api and documentation are burdened by legacy cruft. Hopefully the maintainers will have some sense to prioritize a streamlined documentation that pushes newer syntax. At least we have StackOverflow in the interim.

Comment: @MarkFox agree. I found the worst thing are comments below php manual. People wrote great comments which was good.. many years ago.

Answer (score -3):

It is docummented array push operator. That's all.

Comment: I can find no documentation for a so-called 'array push operator'. `[]` is an array indexer, and when no index value is supplied, one is inferred as the max index of the target array plus 1.

Comment: well that's the reason you can't find anything in the manual - you are too touchy about termilology.